# C Don't include header file/Can't find macro?

Tags: c, macros, header

I'm working on updating a DLL written C and some hours ago I ran into a problem.

Among other things the project use macros for generating common functions for the DLL's modules (structs, "inherited" from Module).

These macros works for all the modules except one macro (GE_module) for one module (Hub).

After have been trying misc. solutions, it is my impression that a header file (macros.h) not is included in another header file (hub.h).

I would not be surprised if the problem, is caused by some magic-visual-studio-behind-the-scene-stuff.
Because hub.h and hub.c is copied from template files and then included in the project, though most of the other module are copies too.

Hope someone here is able to solve this problem, for I ran out of ideas a while back,

Instead of longer description of the problem, I show the relevant code with comments about the problem.

And sorry for not being able to find better tags and title for this problem, but I'm rather clueless wherein the problem lies.

---

Edit/Update:

How I (sort of) figured out, why the 2 hub functions, not are visible in module.h.
hub.h is included in module.h and project.h. If project.h don't include hub, module.h can see the functions. Downside of course is that project.c no longer work.

Spend some time moving #includes up and down in misc. files, but unable to find an include order that works.

So for being able to continue work t my part of the project, I decided using the copy of the troublesome macro i hub.h and let a more experienced c programmer at the project, solve this issue.

I look forward to hear the explanation/solution for this, for I'm quite puzzled.

**stdafx.h**

```
#include "dll/macros.h"
```

**macros.h**

```
#define GE_module_init(Istruct) BOOL module_ ## Istruct ## _init(Module* IImodule)
#define GE_module_delete(Istruct) BOOL module_ ## Istruct ## _delete(Module* IImodule)
#define GE_module(Istruct)         \
    GE_module_init(Istruct);       \
    GE_module_delete(Istruct);
```

**hub.h**

```
// Tried:
//    Restarted Visual Studio
//    Deleted build folders/files
//    Deleted .sou
//    Checking for tyops, again and again.

#include <dll/macros.h> // Don't help
#include "dll/macros.h" // Don't help
#include "../../../macros.h" // Don't help

// Copied from /macros.h. No warning about it's overridden
#define GE_module_init(Istruct) BOOL module_ ## Istruct ## _init(Module* IImodule)
// Copied from /macros.h. No warning about it's overridden
#define GE_module_delete(Istruct) BOOL module_ ## Istruct ## _delete(Module* IImodule)
// If renaming DD() to GE_module():
//    init and delete functions is visible in module.c
//    The functions is called according to trace.log
//    No warning about it's overridden
#define DD(Istruct)         \
    GE_module_init(Istruct);       \
    GE_module_delete(Istruct);

// Hub is written in black, eg. not highlighted by Visual Studio as other modules is.
GE_module(Hub); // Compiler don't complain though
```

**module.c**

```
#include "dll/module/h/hub/hub.h"

#define FRIEND_DLL_module_init_delete_list(Istruct)                                            \
    f_delete_list    [Istruct ## _Module_Type] = &module_ ## Istruct ## _delete;\

BOOL FRIEND_DLL_module_init()
{
    // Error C2065 'module_Hub_delete': undeclared identifier
    // And not C2065 as init()
    FRIEND_DLL_module_init_delete_list(Hub);
}

#define module_create_init_sub_case(Istruct)         \
    case Istruct ## _Module_Type:                    \
        return module_ ## Istruct ## _init(Imodule);

BOOL module_create_init_sub(Module* Imodule)
{
    switch (Imodule->type)
    {
        // Warning C4013 'module_Hub_init' undefined; assuming
        // And not C2065 as init()
        module_create_init_sub_case(Hub)
    }
}
```

Comment: Concerning your comment at the macros: The preprocessor is a quite simple search-and-replace engine that knows nothing about C. If you don't have `DD(anything)` in your source the macro will not be used. Since I don't use VS I don't know how to do this, but GCC can be called with `-E` to produce the C source **after** the preprocessor ran. This output is quite enlighting to find macro and other problems.

Comment: What error messages do you get?